# JavaScript regex to match numbers in array

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I have the following text:

```
 {"status": "ok","data": {"grpd": 0,"obj": 073741824,"objInst": 0,"no": null,"values": [3.523422,0,-323123123,3.423,9223372036854775807,0,"test 123.32",0,0,"",0,0]}}
```

I need to match and place quotes around the numbers in the array "values" so its result should be:

```
 {"status": "ok","data": {"grpd": 0,"obj": 073741824,"objInst": 0,"no": null,"values": ["3.523422","0","-323123123","3.423","9223372036854775807","0","test 123.32","0","0","","0","0"]}}
```

The numbers can be with float point, negative and normal.

Comment: Use a JSON parser.  If I could comment this a dozen times, I would.  You might use a regex along the way, but regex should not be the primary solution here I think.

Comment: Why make numbers into strings though? If there's one thing I've learned it's let primitive types retain their native type.

Comment: Most likely you are taking the wrong approach and no need to convert numbers to strings. Since they are numbers...

Comment: I am converting them because I need to work with big numbers, which JS doesn't support, I only need to get these values and place them on the page. Big number is this: 9223372036854775807. Try to place it to your console like a number.
If there is better way to do this I will be happy to use it but I don't know it.
So I am converting them to string and then parse them with JSON parser.

Comment: how do you generate this JSON? why don't you make `obj.data.values` an `String[]` before/when building this JSON? Is there really a problem with these numbers being numbers and not strings, when you only want to *place them on the page*, as you said? So many questions, just to avoid this hack

Comment: This JSON is generated on other side, they are generated by device, the device is using them I can't change them because this is part of other team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really can't change the original JSON to use strings for numbers that aren't within the range supported by JS then you could use something like this:

```js
var json = '{"status": "ok","data": {"grpd": 0,"obj": 073741824,"objInst": 0,"no": null,"values": [3.523422,0,-323123123,3.423,9223372036854775807,0,"test 123.32",0,0,"",0,0, "test \\u0022 123", "test \\" 123"]}}';

var inString = false;
var inNumber = false;
var out = '';

for (var index = 0, len = json.length ; index < len ; ++index) {
    var chr = json.charAt(index);
    
    switch (chr) {
        case '"':
            inString = !inString;
            break;
            
        case '\\':
            out += chr + json.charAt(index + 1);
            ++index;
            continue;
            
        case '-':
        case '.':
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            if (!inString && !inNumber) {
                out += '"';
                inNumber = true;
            }
            
            break;
            
        default:
            if (inNumber) {
                inNumber = false;
                out += '"';
            }
    }
    
    out += chr;
}

console.log(out);
```

Handling the numbers in strings is too tricky using a RegExp so I haven't even tried. I've assumed the JSON is valid... my crude parser won't cope at all well if it isn't. I've also ignored the `7e5` notation for numbers, that would need a bit of extra work to avoid matching the `e` in `true`.

I haven't explicitly targeted the array `values` but it could be adapted accordingly. How exactly you'd do that depends on whether you want to cope with generic JSON or something a little more targeted to your exact format. You might only put quotes around numbers once they get to a certain length, for example. That would be easy to add by tracking the exact index that a number starts at rather than just using an `isNumber` flag.

If I was going to use something like this in production I would write a shed load of unit tests to ensure it really does work.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do it by regex then you may try this.

```js
const regex = /(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(?![^,]*")/g;
const str = `{"status": "ok","data": {"grpd": 0,"obj": 073741824,"objInst": 0,"no": null,"values": [3.523422,0,-323123123,3.423,9223372036854775807,0,"test 123.32",0,0,"",0,0]}}`;
const subst = `"$1"`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPIrbo/3)

UPDATE AS per the comment:

```
(\:\s*|,|\[|\{)\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=[,\]\}])
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/rPIrbo/4)

```js
const regex = /(\:\s*|,|\[|\{)\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=[,\]\}])/g;
const str = `{"status": "ok","data": {"grpd": 0,"obj": 073741824,"objInst": 0,"no": null,"values": [3.523422,0,-323123123,3.423,"test 123.3,2",0,"test 123.32",0,0,"","adsa22s22",0]}}`;
const subst = `$1"$2"`;


const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't believe this works for the `"test 123.32"` example found in the original test data.

Comment: Just one more question, if I have 
","adsa22s22","
it will match 2 also, how can I escape them matching?

Comment: @MilenGrigorov does that answer your problem now ?

Comment: I can't speak as to the OP's requirements but something like `"test 123.32, 16"` would be very difficult to handle correctly using a RegExp.

Comment: Oh @skirtle just gave good example, now I am wondering if it possible to catch every single case.

Comment: @skirtle yet another good catch, I have added another option for such cases...  Milen you may try the second option too if the situation mentioned being produced

Comment: I don't know whether I'm really helping here. I could keep going, coming up with more and more awkward test cases. e.g. `["[234,456]"]`. Even if you have a RegExp that checks for quotes it gets difficult to avoid falling over `\"` escapes within strings. It might be possible to cover all cases with a RegExp (not convinced) but this is why I proposed a non-RegExp solution in my answer.

Comment: Well this case doesn't seem well structured to me... anyway... thanks for the input

Comment: @skirtle sorry I didn't see you answer before until now, I just missed it, both answers are good!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the data and convert it into string as shown below:

```js
var data =  {"status": "ok","data": {"grpd": 0,"obj": 073741824,"objInst": 0,"no": null,"values": [3.523422,0,-323123123,3.423,9223372036854775807,0,"test 123.32",0,0,"",0,0]}}

var values = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < data.data.values.length ; i ++) {
    values.push(String(data.data.values[i]));
}

data.data.values = values;

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have a loop to check the value is a number or float value and convert to string.

```js
var obj1 = {"status": "ok","data": {"grpd": 0,"obj": 073741824,"objInst": 0,"no": null,"values": [3.523422,0,-323123123,3.423,9223372036854775807,0,"test 123.32",0,0,"",0,0]}};

obj1.data.values.forEach(function(value, index, theArray) {
 if (!isNaN(value) || value.toString().indexOf('.') != -1)
    {
       theArray[index] = value.toString();
    }
});

console.log(obj1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the big numbers will be lost with this method.

Comment: Javascript does not support large numbers as they truncate them so to preserve them you need to send those as a string from server itself

Comment: Yes, I know  that and that's why I ask the question. But I can't change the server, this is server on specific device, and can't be changed like that.

Answer (score 0):

Parse them into a JS object first

```
var obj = JSON.parse( jsonString );
```

then

```
obj.data.values = obj.data.values.map( function( item ){ return !isNaN( item ) ? String( item ) : item; });
```

Convert it back to JSON string format

```
jsonString  = JSON.stringify( obj );
```

However, if the numerals are beyond what javascript objects can take, then use this regex based solution

```js
var str = '{"status": "ok","data": {"grpd": 0,"obj": 073741824,"objInst": 0,"no": null,"values": [3.523422,0,-323123123,3.423,9223372036854775807,0,"test 123.32",0,0,"",0,0]}}';

str = str.replace(/[,|\[](\-){0,1}\d+(\.\d+)*(?=[,|\]])/g, function(match){ var firstChar = match.charAt(0); match = match.substring( 1 ); return firstChar + "\"" + match + "\"" ; });

console.log( str );
```

Comment: I am converting them because I need to work with big numbers, which JS doesn't support, I only need to get these values and place them on the page. Big number is this: 9223372036854775807. Try to place it to your console like a number. If there is better way to do this I will be happy to use it but I don't know it. So I am converting them to string and then parse them with JSON parser.

Comment: @MilenGrigorov I got it now, parsing to json/number approach won't work.

Comment: it works good now, thank you but I already  accepted the answer by Rizwan Tuman.

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = JSON.parse(response);
obj.values = obj.values.map(item => typeof item === 'number' ? '"'+item+'"');
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

or with es5

```
obj.values = obj.values.map(function(item) {
  return typeof item === 'number' ? '"'+item+'"';
}
```

or instead of typeof item === 'number' you can use ! isNaN(item)

Comment: When I hit the first line "let obj = JSON.parse(response);" I lost the big numbers because JS doesn't support them.
Thanks anyway, some guys above give me good regex.